# Как перейти на другую страницу?

Tags: javascript

```js
var login = document.getElementById("login"); 
var pass = document.getElementById("password"); 
var vxd = document.getElementById("vxod"); 
var check = document.getElementById("remember");
vxd.onclick = function()
{
 document.location.href = "http://www.site.ru";
 alert('ok');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
  <style>
   @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700);
   body {
    background: #563c55 url(images/blurred.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
   }
   .container > header h1,
   .container > header h2 {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   }
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
   <section class="main">
    <form class="form-3">
        <p class="clearfix">
            <label for="login">Логин</label>
            <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Логин">
        </p>
        <p class="clearfix">
            <label for="password">Пароль</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Пароль"> 
        </p>
        <p class="clearfix">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
            <label for="remember">Запомнить меня</label>
        </p>
        <p class="clearfix">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="vxod" value="Вход">
        </p>       
    </form>​
   </section>
        </div>
  <script src="login.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ничего не происходит, хотя событие `onclick` точно происходит

Comment: Пример рабочий, возможно на странице от куда вырезали код есть ещё элемент с id="submit"

Comment: исправил id на vxod все равно не реагирует

Comment: Я вставил себе код HTML и JS с вопроса и всё отработало, возможно ошибка синтаксиса в login.js или ещё где в js, проверьте в консоли разработчика есть ли ошибки в консоли.

Comment: ошибок в консоли нет. я весь скрипт вставил в вопрос, но там и ошибкам быть негде

Comment: в консоли даже не отображается попытка зайти на http://www.site.ru

Comment: может у type="submit" нет свойства href и поэтому не переходит? попробовал на type="button" перешло на новую страницу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш код рабочий, есть одна небольшая загвоздка в типе кнопки. Когда Вы пишете:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="vxod" value="Вход">
```

где указываете `type="submit"` - в таком случае Вы отправляете данные с формы `<form>`, то есть это кнопка для отправки формы. Если указать `type="button"`  то это просто кнопка, которая не отправит форму. Поэтому если изменить код вот так, то следующий `JavaScript` сделает все как, как Вы ожидаете:

```js
document.getElementById("vxod").onclick = function()
{
  document.location.href = "http://ru.stackoverflow.com";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="submit" id="vxod" value="Вход">
```

Кстати, если не указать тип кнопки, то значение по умолчанию типа кнопки - `submit`, что означает, что это кнопка для отправки данных формы на сервер.

Но и это еще не всё. Если же Вы все же хотите, чтобы тип кнопки был `submit`, но не хотите отправлять данные с формы на сервер - Вам достаочно внутри обработчика, в конце, написать `return false;`. Если функция возвращает `false`, то отправки не будет, а если `true` - выполниться отправка формы. Вот такой код не  отправит данные с формы:

```js
document.getElementById("vxod").onclick = function()
{
  document.location.href = "http://ru.stackoverflow.com";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="vxod" value="Вход">
```